# Creating a large(e.g. 450MB+) bloomfilter in Java

Tags: java, bloom-filter

- I have an application running on Java and I need to create a bloomfilter of size 450MB+. Refer to the requirements: https://hur.st/bloomfilter/?n=400M&p=0.01&m=&k= This is to support adding 400million+ records with a false-positive probability of 0.01.
- I am using this bloom filter library https://github.com/MagnusS/Java-BloomFilter, but it seems they are using `int` to access the bitSetSize, and there has been multiple typecasts to an integer. Hence, no matter what maximum size I keep getting is INT_MAX (i.e. 2147483647 bits or 268MB).
- I was also looking at another library https://github.com/Baqend/Orestes-Bloomfilter.  But their source code reveals using integers instead of Long for bit size.
- Is there a standard library to support the creation of 450MB+ bloomfilter? Or would I fork these libraries to refactor the integer typecasts? Any suggestions is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: `guava`? how you know the size, though? and what is that size _exactly_ anyway?

Comment: I need to insert 400 Million records in the bloomfilter and have a false positive probability less than 0.01. Entering these parameters in bloomfilter online calculator shows I might need 450MB of BF size. Refer https://hur.st/bloomfilter

I am successfully able to create a bloomfilter to add 200million records with 0.01 falsePositive whose size is around 240MB. And this is working good.

Need now to increase this bloomfilter capability to add around 400M records with same 0.01 false positive probability.

Comment: ok, I took a look at that page. that is not memory... you will need _a lot_ more then 450 MB.

Comment: Yes, during the 200million records experiment, I have created the BF and uploaded it in the S3. In that case, the size stored in the S3 was around 240MB. You are right, the memory was much higher probably memory consumption of the pod I was using, was around 5 GB.

Here I meant the size of bloomfilter when saving it in a S3 bucket.

Comment: from what I see, you can achieve that via `guava`, look into that.